# How to disable submit button with jQuery..?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to disable a submit button and change it to say Processing when the user clicks it so they won't (and can't) click the button again.

Here's what I've got...

```
<input type="submit" onclick="jQuery(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('Processing'); return true;" class="button" value="Place Order">
```

With that, when I click the button it does change to say Processing, however, it doesn't actually submit the form either.  I just get stranded there.

I tried changing onclick to onsubmit, but that didn't have any effect at all, and just left me with the original problem of being able to keep clicking the button.

You can see the page here:  http://woo.angelleye.com/checkout/review-order/

It'll load with an empty cart, but you can see what happens when you click the Place Order button.  If I remove the jQuery off that button then it would just fine, but with an error, of course, because of no items.

Any  info on how I can get this working would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: It should be submitting. You are not canceling any event.

Comment: @true, it's not, though.  I updated the question with a link to the page I'm working on.

Comment: I don't get your problem now

Comment: By the way, I noticed in your form that, your input is not used in the correct way. change `<input ...></input>` to `<input ... />`

Comment: @HadiRasekh, thanks.  I'm working on this WP plugin that is rather messy at the moment.  Trying to clean stuff like that up.  That's on my list already.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(event){
    $(this).attr('disabled','true');
    $(this).val('Processing...');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. 
Cover the fields with a form tag

```
 $("#form").submit(function{
         $("#button").val("Processing...").attr("disabled",true);
         return true;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In forms, its better to add your event to your form not to your submit button. It means, you want your submit button to get `disabled` when your form got submited.

try this:

```
$('form').on('submit',function(){
    $(this).find('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

If you want to do it inline, take a look on this code:

```
<form action="test.php" method="get" onsubmit="$(this).find('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled','disabled');">
 <input type="text" />
 <input type="submit"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Any way to do it inline?

Comment: you can do it like: `onsubmit="$(this).find('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled','disabled');`

Comment: A very bad idea to merge inline click handler with jQuery. __Keep them seperate__

Answer (score 0):

Your problem does not lie in the javascript you have shown. It lies on line 138. View the source and have a look at it:

`$('form.checkout').unbind( 'submit' );`

This prevents the submit event from firing. Remove that and the form will submit.

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function (e) {
    // custom handling here
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

hope it helps